# Setting a pointer to another pointer breaks reference somehow

Tags: c++, pointers

Based on my understanding of pointers here, `currentDancer` and `pushups` should be the same reference.  And yet if I set `currentDancer` I can't use it.

```
Dancer *currentDancer;
DancerPushups pushups; // DancerPushups inherits from public Dancer

void setup() {
  pushUps.init(FL1, FL2, FR1, FR2, BR1, BR2, BL1, BL2);
  currentDancer = &pushups; // try to set pushups as the current dancer
}

void loop() {
  pushups.onBeatStart(duration);        // works great! :D
  currentDancer->onBeatStart(duration); // does nothing D:
}
```

What part of pointer handling am I failing here? How can I get `Dancer *currentDancer` to point to an arbitrary instance that I already have created?

---

UPDATE:

Is this an inheritance issue?

```
void Dancer::onBeatStart(float duration) {
  // no-op  
}

// DancerPushups : public Dancer
void DancerPushups::onBeatStart(float duration) {
  all(the, cool, stuff, that, isnt, happening);
}
```

Because I'm casting the `DancerPushups` to a `Dancer*` type, am I not running my subclasses method?

Comment: The code you've shown is correct. Can you post a complete example that replicates your problem?

Comment: This is going to sound like a really dumb question, but I gotta ask: Is `doStuff()` *virtual* ?

Comment: What code could make those two lines not equivalent? I've verified that `currentDancer == &pushups` and that `currentDancer->FL1 == pushups.FL1` so the pointer should be the same, and the pointers the reference contains should be the same. I'm not sure what relevant bit to include :(

Comment: What kind of function is `doStuff()` – isn't it virtual? is it declared in the base class only or overloaded in an inheriting class? Is your poblem really it 'does nothing' or may be 'does not compile'?

Comment: ^ See my update about how that method is declared. I think may be doing inheritance wrong...

Comment: Again, is `onBeatStart` **virtual** ? Post the method *declaration* in the `Dancer` class.

Comment: @WhozCraig no. Is it supposed to be?

Comment: @AlexWayne it *has* to be if you want polymorphism to work (non-static-poly; no CRTP flamethrowers please). Otherwise you code is just saying "go execute `Dancer::onBeatStart` and that is exactly what it is doing. The idea of poly is via virtual provision. Make sure it is declared `virtual void onBeatStart(float duration);` in the class declaration of `Dancer`. Your *intent* is that anything derived from `Dancer` can implement that method, and *their* implementation will invoke from a `Dancer*` or `Dancer&`, right?

Comment: Yes, `Dancer` defines an interface and actual different methods of dancing will be different subclasses. If you make that an answer I'll totally accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `onBeatStart` is not a `virtual` member function. When you call `currentDancer->onBeatStart()`, you are calling the base class implementation, which, as you have shown, does nothing.